# Call API repeatedly until entire data has been is downloaded data

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a use case where I want to call a web API for each user repeatedly until entire data is downloaded.

The web API that I have, allows maximum 100 records to be fetched for a user per API request. I can specify `startTime` and end timestamp of the records to be download for that user:

```
void downloadRecord(String userId, recordStartTime, recordEndTime, int countOfRecord, ResultCallBack)
```

If the number of records between `recordStartTime` and `recordEndTime` is more than 100, then API response only returns 100 records. And then I have to loop through to call this apis with new start time (time of the 100th record just downloaded), until all the records are downloaded.

```
final long recordStartTime = timeStampFrom2DaysAgo//;
Observable.from(arrayListOfUserIds).flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<?>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<?> call(String userId) {
        long recordEndTime = getCurrentTimeMS();
        //keep downloading records 
        downloadRecord(userId, recordStartTime, recordEndTime, 100, new ResultCallBack() {
            //if records are < 100 then stop 
            //else keep downloading 
        });
    }
}).subscribe();
```

Please suggest if there is a RxJava sample code that I can use to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a perfect use-case for Observable.generate (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.generate). Unfortunately I'm afraid RxJava doesn't have such method :(

Answer (score 4):

**This is a case of circularly dependent Observables.** Imagine you have one Observable for the requests and one Observable for the responses. `requests` Observable emits some `DownloadParams` objects, containing userId, recordStartTime, recordEndTime and countOfRecord, hence `Observable<DownloadParams> requests`. `responses` Observable emits the list of records, i.e., `Observable<List<Record>> responses`.

`responses` obviously depends on `requests`, but the not so obvious part is that we need `requests` also to depend on `responses`, because the next download from the server, with certain `DownloadParams`, depends on what response we got from the previous download. For completeness, `requests` actually also depends on some initialization Observable which emits the userId to perform the first download. You can replace this initialization Observable with just a `.startWith(firstDownloadParams)`.

Anyway, the hard part is expressing the cyclic dependency. The good news is this is possible in Rx, and has been [the focus of Cycle.js framework based on RxJS](https://github.com/erykpiast/cyclejs-stream). The bad news is that we cannot solve this without Subjects, which might be rather undesirable.

It is better to keep RxJava code as functional as possible, but by attempting to do that we reach a problem. If we try to declare the Observables as a function of others, we get:

```
Observable<DownloadParams> requests = responses.flatMap( /* ... */ )
    .startWith(firstDownloadParams);
Observable<List<Record>> responses = requests.flatMap( /* ... */ );
```

This doesn't compile because the first declaration needs the second declaration, and vice versa. This is how subjects can help. We declare either one of those Observables as a Subject:

```
PublishSubject<List<Record>> responsesProxy = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<DownloadParams> requests = responsesProxy.flatMap( /* ... */ )
    .startWith(firstDownloadParams);
Observable<List<Record>> responses = requests.flatMap( /* ... */ );
```

The Subject `responsesProxy` will act as a proxy for `responses`, so that we are able to declare `requests` depending on `responsesProxy`. But now we need `responsesProxy` to imitate `responses`. We do that by adding this:

```
responses.subscribe(responsesProxy);
```

This closes the loop in the circular dependency, but just remember to properly dispose also the Subject since we made the subscription above.

Now we just need to fill in the transformations in those `flatMap`. In `requests.flatMap( )` you should perform the network call that downloads the list of records. You probably want to handle this as an Observable, not as a callback, to ease the interplay with the rest of the RxJava code.

In `responsesProxy.flatMap( )` you should check if the list of records are 100 or more and create the next `DownloadParams` with a new recordStartTime, wrapped as `Observable.just(newDownloadParams)`. If less than 100, then return `Observable.empty()`.

Answer (score 2):

This can get complicated: see the example gist [here](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/f702d8e6b17618802e64).

Basically you need to trampoline the requests concerning the subsequent time windows to be queried. Note that `BufferUntilSubscriber` is internal, but RxJava doesn't have any official `Subject` variant that caches values up until a subscription happens and then discards the cache.

**Edit**: updated gist so it doesn't trigger a `MissinBackpressureException`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you said indeed this has got really complicated. To understand your solution I need to study  RxJava deeply. I am not yet there :)