# How to handle circularly dependent observables in RxJS?

Tags: circular-dependency, observable, rxjs

Let's say e.g. that somewhere on a server there is a mapping between
integers and names and a web page provides a simple input where a user
can enter a number and is given the corresponding name.

In its basic form, this problem is simple:

```
const input$          = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(..., "input");
const request$        = input$.map( ... );
const serverResponse$ = request$.flatMap( askServer );
```

Now I would like to cache the results so that a request is only
done when the number is not in the cache.

```
const input$          = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(..., "input");
// request$ should now also depend on cache$
const request$        = ???;
const serverResponse$ = request$.flatMap( askServer );
const cache$          = serverResponse$.scan( ... );
```

But now `request$` depends on `cache$` which depends on a `serverResponse$`
which in turn depends on `request$`.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Short answer : use a subject. Long answer : see here the response by André Staltz : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391212/call-api-repeatedly-until-entire-data-has-been-is-downloaded-data/30427848#30427848

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduce a `Subject` as a proxy at some point in the cycle in the dependency graph, then mirror the behavior of the real Observable (`cache$`) onto the proxy Subject (`proxyCache$`).

```
const input$          = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(..., "input");
const proxyCache$     = new Rx.Subject();
const request$        = input$.merge(proxyCache$).map( ... );
const serverResponse$ = request$.flatMap( askServer );
const cache$          = serverResponse$.scan( ... );
cache$.subscribe(proxyCache$);
```